# Laravel: How to install php7 with Homestead

Tags: php, laravel

I m a newbie and learning Laravel. I m having a trouble with install php and homestead.
As I read in Laravel Official Website:

> Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant box that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine.

So I think I do not need to install php in my local machine ??? But when I install composer, it requires PHP.exe and I cannot browse that PATH. I misunderstand here. I have been stuck in this problem and research many websites for whole day, so I think better to ask (even if it is stupid question). Could anyone explain for me please...

---EDIT_NEW---

This is my completed steps to use Laravel:

1. Install git
2. Install virturalbox
3. Install vagrant
4. vagrant box add laravel/homestead
5. git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
6. cd Homestead, bash init.sh
7. Configure Homestead
8. add to Hosts file

Now I have to install laravel, it requires composer. Composer installation requires php.exe PATH. But if I dont use XAMPP or others local development environment, how can I install Composer ?

(Note: Maybe I misunderstand here "without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine").

Comment: Did you [try following the installation instructions for Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead)? Was there a particular area you were having trouble with?

Comment: I did read all the docs and cannot find the way, i did install homestead. Then I install laravel (requires composer), so I have to install composer but without tool like xampp..., I cannot find the way to install composer with php included in homestead.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I m using windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you executing composer "inside" Homested vagrant VM or in windows "cmd"? In the first case it's strange in the second of course it doesn't work. You need to acces the Homestead VM via SSH

Comment: Could you explain more to me please? I dont understand Homestead clearly enough.

Comment: Your answer and Laracast did help me alot, I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I was also stuck with the same case as @PeterCow, can you explain it in here or edit the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, with your answers and Laracast Video: https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two. Now I got the answer.

Answer (score -2):

You need to follow some steps to running Laravel in your system (windows 10).

1) Install `XAMPP` or `WAMPP`, you can download `XAMPP` from [Here](https://www.apachefriends.org).

2) Install composer, find it from [Here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows).

3) Install `GIT` (optional).

Than go for create New Laravel App.

1) Open Terminal -> goto `C:/xampp/htdocs/`

2) `composer create-project laravel/laravel <App_Name>`

3) `php artisan serve`

Comment: MUST I use XAMPP (or others like XAMPP) to install php on local, and then install Composer with PATH to PHP IN XAMPP ? Is there any other ways ?

Comment: Sorry about that, because I didnot understand clearly so my question maybe not clear. Is there any way to install composer with PHP NOT LOCALLY INSTALLED ?

Comment: Did you mean install composer before install PHP?

Comment: No, I mean I install Composer after, but the thing is, I want to use PHP7 in Homestead (What included in Homestead Introduction - Included Software). But I dont see any thing relate to php(php7) in Homestead. The normal workflow of this installation is (imo): Install xampp, install composer, install lavarel. But any other way to install composer then install laravel without installing Xampp (or others)?

Comment: XAMPP is a package it provides Apache, Mysql, Perl and PHP.

Comment: If you dont want to install XAMPP, then you can manually install apache2, php and mysql by your self.

Comment: Hmmm, I misunderstand here. It means that: I MUST install apache, mysql, php (environment)... Why the official laravel docs said: "Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant box that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine."